# Get object comments with their author

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I need object comment list with their authors for extraction statistical information about author and their comments. [FB Graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/object/comments) allow me to get comment list but there no way to get information about comment author.

Comment: did you find any solution on this?

Comment: No. Looks there no solution for that.

Comment: Yes you can, You have to pass page access token rather than app access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.11 of the Graph API, you can only get user information about comment authors by using a Page Token. You can only get a Page Token if you manage the Page. **There is no way to get the author data if you do not manage the Page**.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90

Also, make sure you ask for the relevant fields: `/post-id/comments?fields=message,from`

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question well. I want to get list of dependencies user - comment count for competition. From graph api I can get list of comments like /{object-id}/comments . But it returns only created_time, message and id of comment. I need a way to identificate who wrote this comment.

Comment: i know, it is a well known issue because it was changed recently. read my answer again, it is all in there. i also added some information about declarative fields, just in case you do not know about that.

Comment: also hightlighted the very important part. no ownership, no page token, no user data.

Comment: @luschn I would think that having manage_pages permission would be enough, wouldn't it?  I am the admin of a page so I would think I have it.  I'm using a REST Source task in SSIS to pull the data, passing in the appID and secret for the app I created.  Does the app need specific permissions?

I can get the information when I do it on my own page, but not the company page.  My only thought is that the token being passed is not being 'seen' as a page token.

Comment: manage_pages should be enough, yes. maybe you do not have the required user role in your company page? do you really get a page token for the company page?

Comment: Have this changed ? I made an app that used PageToken to retrieve the 'from' field, working great, but now is not retrieving the user, except if the comment is made by me or in behalf of the page. But I wont get the 'from' from other users.

Comment: are you sure you are using a page token? did you debug it?